# Extract value from one table if their values match the 2nd table

Tags: sql, json, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

**Background:**

I have two tables within a CosmosDB database that hold key:value documents within their containers.
T1 and T2

```
T1
 
Id: 111
ems_featurecategory: 1234
ems_name: "win"



T2
 
feature_category: "win"
feature_category: "hello"
```

I wish to query cosmosdb so that I:

Return the value from T1 ems_featurecategory key if the ems_name value from T1 matches the feature_category value from T2.

**Desired Output:**

So since the ems_name key's value from T1 matches the featurecategory's key's value from T2

```
ems_name: "win"
featurecategory: "win",
```

the value that will be returned will be:  1234

**My approach:**

JOIN the two tables and perform a query such as:

```
 SELECT c.emsfeaturecategory, c.ems_name, f.feature_category
 FROM c 
 JOIN f in c.id
 WHERE array_contains(['',''],c.id,true)
 AND c.ems_name = featurecategory...
```

I am not sure how to write this query out successfully. Any suggestions or advice is helpful.

Comment: cross-container search can not be done.Cosmos db is different with  relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cosmosdb,cross-container search can not be done.I suggest you change your schema of your document like this:

```
T1
     
{
    "id": "111",
    "ems_featurecategory": 1234,
    "ems_name": "win",
    "feature_category": [
        "win",
        "hello"
    ]
}
```

Then,you can use this sql:

```
 SELECT value c.ems_featurecategory     
 FROM c 
 where array_contains(c.feature_category,c.ems_name,true)
```

Here is the output of my test:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
select c.emsfeaturecategory, c.ems_name, f.feature_category
from table1 c
join table2 f on c.ems_name = f.featurecategory
```

using your example it will return the following:

```
emsfeaturecategory | ems_name | feature_category
1234               | win      | hello
```

I'm using the columns you specified. Later on you say you only want the 1234 to be outputted. Then you would simply do:

```
select c.emsfeaturecategory
from table1 c
join table2 f on c.ems_name = f.featurecategory
```

Note: join is functionally the same as 'inner join'

You can read more about joins [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Let me try this, and so the result should return the 1234 value? I will try thank you

Comment: Quick question: so table 1 and table 2 are actually two different containers. Could this still be done?

Comment: Syntax might be different. I gave you a solution in SQL. Reference this for azure syntax for joins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join